# Excel - calculating the percentage of individuals that return over consecutive months

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet of patients collecting medication over several months. The patients are grouped according to the month when they first collected medication.

[image]

For each patient group, I want to calculate the percentage of patients that return during each of the following months to collect medication again. I have inserted an example of this in the spreadsheet, highlighted in yellow.

How can I automate this calculation in Excel?

Comment: Can you explain the manual calculation you are doing please.

Comment: For each month, I divide the number of patients in a group by the number of patients in that group in the month of their first collection. For example,  for the individuals who made their first collection in 201411, I divide their number in each month by their number in the first month. That way I can see what percentage of the individuals return each month.

Comment: "For the individuals who made their first collection in 201411, I divide their number in each month"  - which Cell(s) is that in?  "by their number in the first month" - which Cell(s) is that in?

Comment: Cell S3 is calculated from C3/C2; cell S4 from C4/C2 and so on...

Answer (score 0):

So if "Cell S3 is calculated from C3/C2; cell S4 from C4/C2 and so on."

The formula you would need is

```
=C3/C$2
```

put that in S3 and then copy and paste it into the cells below S3.

### Explanation

By default addresses in excel are relative so C3 actually means"this row, this column -16" so if you copy it down that relative address will stay the same.
To fix an address we can use the dollar symbols (highlight the address & press f4 on the keyboard) which will fix it to the actual cell C2 not a relative address.

[More Info](http://www.gcflearnfree.org/excel2013/15)

Comment: There is a problem with that formula when I drag it into the subsequent columns after S. As you can see, the first value in these columns is not found in row 2. The first value drops down by one row every time we move from one column to the next after column S.

Comment: In that case you only need to the row part of the formula.  I have updated the answer from =C3/$C$2 to =C3/C$2 which should do what you want.

Comment: That formula does not work. Since the values in row 2 are missing for all columns except C, I run into a division-by-0 error when I drag that formula to the right. I am currently experimenting with this formula: "=INDEX(C2:C16;MATCH(TRUE;INDEX(C2:C16<>"";0);0)). I want to make the cells in columns C:Q all start on row 2. However, with this formula, I keep getting the first value in a column over and over again until the row where the first value appears in the original column. Only after that does Excel give me the following values. How can I correct this?

Comment: Well you will get a div by zero on the cells that reference empty cells.  But from your picture you didn't want any values there so you can just delete the formula as it makes no sense.  Or alternatively just use =IF(ISERROR(C3/C$2),0,C3/C$2)